# Should socket.io join room or listen on unique ID to receive message from server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I working on real-time chat project. Multi user can chat and receive chat in room
Every room have an unique ID.
when user join a room, which case should I use?
Case 1 :

-User emit an event "join" with data is room ID to server, SocketIO server let user join to room with name is ID. Then when user chatting, user emit an event "chat" with chat data to server and server emit that chat to all user in that room by io.in(roomID).emit("chat",chatData)

Case 2 :
When user join room, user can listen an event have name is roomID like

```
socket.on(roomID, handleChatDataFunc)
```

When user chat, it's working like case 1, user emit an event "chat" with chat data to server, but now server will broadcast an event have name is roomID like

```
io.emit(roomID, chat Data);
```

So all user listen an event name roomID will receive chatData
All the chat will be public so I don't need to authenticated user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for a room is so that the server can emit to ONLY those users.  A client pre-declares to the server which things they are interested in so the server knows what to send them and what not to send them.

Your proposal to just have clients listen to msg names that they want means that your server has to send ALL data to ALL users, whether they are listening or not - whether they want that info or not.  That's inefficient (sending data to clients that they don't want or need) and completely impractical with large numbers of clients.